# requestAnimationFrame makes canvas animation buggy

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to create simple canvas animation where a small ball orbits bigger ball. I'm using requestAnimationFrame but it's not working as I though. In other words my animation is sometimes running very slow (can't keep up with the 60fps). I made [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvembzhx/1/) for more visual explanation.

Also here is the javascript I'm using:

```
var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1').getContext('2d');
var layer2 = document.getElementById('layer2').getContext('2d');

var x;
var y;
var angle = 0;

var last_frame = 0;

function render(timestamp) {

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  fps = timestamp - last_frame;
  last_frame = timestamp;

  // optimal framerate would be 60 (~16ms/"loop") -> count ratio according to that
  // for example if fps is 32 -> 32/16 = 2 -> we move ball twice the normal distance
  var delta = fps / 16;

  angle += 0.02 * delta;

  x = 200 + 100 * Math.cos(angle);
  y = 200 + 100 * Math.sin(angle);

  layer1.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  layer1.beginPath();
  layer1.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  layer1.fill();

}
render(16);

layer2.beginPath();
layer2.arc(200, 200, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);
layer2.fill();
```

Is there something wrong with my code or what? I'm trying to make a hybrid mobile game using Cordova (PhoneGap) & canvas but if the performance of Javascript is this bad, I might as well forget this right away.

By the way:
Animation is running quite good (most of the time) with laptop but with Samsung Galaxy A tab requestAnimationFrame gives me like this (60fps, 60fps, 60fps, 29fps, 29fps, 60fps, 60fps, 60fps, 29fps.....)

Comment: What I mean by "not running good" is the kind of lagging every here and there.

Comment: I think that putting this line at the end of function `requestAnimationFrame(render);` will act different since you will call the function recursion after executing first lines of it. try this solution and let me know the result

Comment: Unfortunately that made no difference. The ball is still lagging.

Comment: Have you tried profiling memory? Maybe it's GC that causes drops in FPS? By the way, `fps` is not declared anywhere, so it's global. Also, since you know previous position of smaller ball, why not clear just that area, instead of whole canvas every time?

Comment: Just for experiment, i moved calculations to `requestIdleCallback` and clear only previously drawn area: https://jsfiddle.net/tvembzhx/5/

Comment: I added a snippet that shows gaps in the loop where there's lag.  I had a lot of firefox tabs, thunderbird, and adium running with noticeable lag in the loop. Closing those made the lag go away for me on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The lag is hard to notice but it's there.  I adjusted your code to make the lag more visible.

```js
var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1').getContext('2d');
var layer2 = document.getElementById('layer2').getContext('2d');

var x;
var y;
var angle = 0;
var last_frame = 0;
layer1.globalAlpha = .5;

function render(timestamp) {

  fps = timestamp - last_frame;
  last_frame = timestamp;

  // optimal framerate would be 60 (~16ms/"loop") -> count ratio according to that
  // for example if fps is 32 -> 32/16 = 2 -> we move ball twice the normal distance
  var delta = fps / 16;

  if (angle > Math.PI * 2) {
    layer1.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    angle %= Math.PI * 2;
  }

  angle += 0.02 * delta;
  x = 200 + 100 * Math.cos(angle);
  y = 200 + 100 * Math.sin(angle);

  layer1.beginPath();
  layer1.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  layer1.stroke();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render(16);
layer2.beginPath();
layer2.arc(200, 200, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);
layer2.fill();
```

```css
canvas,
#frames_label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="layer1" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="layer2" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<div id="frames_label"></div>
```